# Code to check if XP Service Pack 3 Installed (And .net 3.5)

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, servicepacks

I want to write a program (in vb.net) that checks a customers configuration to make sure that they're ...

- Running XP service Pack 3
- Running .Net 3.0 or above.
- Give them a warning if they are not running .Net 3.5 or above.

or

- Running Vista Service Pack 1.

How would I do this?
There is a stackoverflow question asking how to tell which version of .NET is installed, but how do I test which O/S & O/S service pack is installed?

[How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not exactly know the version number of Windows XP SP 3 (but should be easy to lookup for you), but here is how you can get version string.

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version); // CLR version
Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion.VersionString); // OS version string
Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion.ServicePack); // OS SP string
```

Version requiredVersion = new Version(5, 1, 2600, 0); // Should be XP Prof. with Service Pack 2 (any revision)
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= requiredVersion.Major
  && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= requiredVersion.Minor
  && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= requiredVersion.Build)
{
    // You are running at least Windows XP Prof. with Service Pack 2 or above!
}

Determin if .NET Framework 3.5 is installed won't be easy because the 3.5 version is only a addon based on 2.0. But you can check if the folder "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5" does exist.

Comment: Note that the code above requires a minor version >= 1.  if the Windows version is more recent--say, 6.0 or some future 7.0 version, for example-- it will not report it as higher than 5.1.2600.0.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article by Microsoft [How to determine the operating system service pack level in Visual Basic .NET or in Visual Basic 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304722/EN-US/)