# Convert XAML WPF Window to WinForm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-forms-designer

Is there any utility or converter to convert XAML WPF window to .Net 2.0 Windows forms form?

Comment: i don't think there are any.. and even if there are.. i wonder how could they flatten the control hierarchy of WPF to winform controls...

Comment: You're right, but i need the basic layout, or the 'figure'

Comment: Couldn't you simply embed your WPF control into WinForms' windows using [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) ?

Comment: But the problem is that i'm using .net 2.0!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and there's unlikely to be anything like this; WPF and WinForms are disparate frameworks, a WPF UI can't really be converted to a WinForms UI due to differences in UI composition, layout differences, different positioning systems, etc.

Comment: I see, the main reason is the different composition way in WPF, but i need a utility to give me a rough WinForm contains the controls in the nearest way they are in the WPF window

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing like that to my knowledge, and I tend to be privy on these sort of things.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool to convert it across. It might be worth using an [ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535812/using-a-custom-wpf-control-in-winforms) to load WPF components in WPF, that way you don't need to convert and can re-use WPF components. If you have a WPF window you would need to convert this to a UserControl to work.

**EDIT:**

[.Net 2 code to load WPF control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298933/loading-net-3-5-wpf-forms-in-a-net-2-0-application/1378896#1378896)

```
    string dllPath = "C:\\ProjectsTest\\TestSolution\\ActiveXUser\\bin\\Debug\\TestControl.dll";
if (!File.Exists(dllPath)) {
    return;
}

string versionInformation = null;
versionInformation = Environment.Version.Major.ToString() + Environment.Version.Minor;

Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);

Type[] mytypes = loadedAssembly.GetTypes();

Type t = mytypes[1];
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

versionInformation = Environment.Version.Major.ToString() + Environment.Version.Minor;
this.Panel1.Controls.Add(obj);
```

Comment: But the problem is that i'm using .net 2.0!! :

Comment: ahh. There's a solution on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298933/loading-net-3-5-wpf-forms-in-a-net-2-0-application/1378896#1378896)

Comment: This won't even compile as `ControlCollection.Add` method takes a `Control` not arbitrary object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this Xaml library for WinForms?

https://winformsxaml.codeplex.com