# How to Convert WPF project to Windows Form Project?

Tags: wpf, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert XAML WPF Window to WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008082/convert-xaml-wpf-window-to-winform)

I have a wpf project and I would like to convert the project to a windows forms project. Are there any tools are available to do this?

Comment: There is no tool/automated way to do this. Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008082/convert-xaml-wpf-window-to-winform

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WPF controls in Winforms, there is an other way:

a control for WinForms that allows you to use a WPF control in WinForms. It is called [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since the complete Markup and Design Language XAML differes completly from the way WinForms makes its markup.
Also the .NET WPF Framework contains lots of unique Classes behaviors and functionalities, they are also totally different.

Anyways: Why would you try to convert a WPF project back to WinForms? ;)

Comment: i want use some controls that are in wpf project in windowsforms application,that controls are not available in windowsforms application.

Comment: There is a control for WinForms that allows you to use a WPF control in WinForms. It is called ElementHost: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx

Comment: k..i wil send my project to u.can u tel , whatever controls that i used in wpf project is can be used in windows form application?

Comment: I can give no guarrantees but in general you should be able to use any WPF control. Just read the documentation and try it.

Comment: maybe because mono STILL doesn't support WPF at all and at least somewhat supports winforms.