# Setup requires .NET Framework v1.1.4322 - but i already have all frameworks 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 !

Tags: .net

Tried to install some program, it gives above message requiring 1.1.4322.

BUT as the title says, all the frameworks are already installed on my WinXP SP2, if i inspect C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

The machine has VS2008 which essentially required full installation of Framework 3.5 SP1.

Any ideas? (i know, just re-install framework 1.1 again, but why should i - I can see all Frameworks are installed, and things are supposed to be backward compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how many files are in the 1.1 directory.

I've seen cases where that directory will exist, and only contain a couple of files (presumably left there by some poorly-written setup script), without an installation of the 1.1 framework.

Comment: Too right. I checked immediately after posting the question and only a couple of files in the 1.1 folders ! Similarly only a few files in the 1.0 folder (Presumably both folders created by the 3.5 SP1 install).

Answer (score 4):

The setup you are running is checking whether the .Net 1.1 is installed in the registry (which is [the official way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)), instead of looking at the presence of the `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322` folder.

So you probably don't have .Net 1.1 installed and the folder is created by some tools that add some files they need to support that .Net version without checkin if it is installed or not (with the rationale that if it's not, but later on it is installed, they'll just start working for it).

Note that certain applications require exactly .Net 1.1 and can't run on later versions (because of certain breaking changes between 1.1 and 2.0).

And to solve your actual problem of not having 1.1, you can [get the installer for it from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569264.aspx). Note that if you are using ASP.NET on that machine, you might have to re-register ASP.NET 3.5 and configure IIS to use it after you install 1.1.

Comment: Your right too but i've taken the first response as answer, doesn't allow me to mark both as answers. And thanks for additional info too.

Comment: @joedotnot - @SLkas answer is correct (albeit a bit terse) and was posted before mine, so I have no beef with you accepting it over my. :-)

Comment: @penov, If I have installed NET 3.5, and now install .NET 1.1, how can I register asp.net 3.5 and configure IIS ?

Comment: If you have installed 1.1 after 3.5, you can always use aspnet_regiis.exe from 3.5 install location to register it again with IIS.

Comment: New installer link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 1.1 Redistributable Package

Answer (score 1):

When you install the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, it will also install the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and the .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 behind the scenes.  You cannot use the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 unless you also have the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.0 SP2 installed.  Therefore, you will not be allowed to uninstall the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or 3.0 SP2 if you have the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed.  If you try to uninstall those versions of the .NET Framework, their uninstall processes will block and tell you that they are needed by another application on your system.

The .NET Framework 1.0 and .NET Framework 1.1 can be installed side-by-side with the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5.  Most applications that were created for the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 will automatically use the .NET Framework 2.0 instead if it is installed on the system.  In most cases, that means you do not need to keep the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 installed on your system if you already have the .NET Framework 2.0 installed.

However, there are some applications that are configured to require a specific version of the .NET Framework, even if later versions of the .NET Framework are installed.  If you have any applications like that on your system and try to run them without installing the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1, you will get an error message that looks like the following:

> MyApplication.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error
>
> To run this application, you first must install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework:    v1.1.4322  Contact your application
>   publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of
>   the .NET Framework.
>
> OK

In the above error message, the version number will be v1.0.3705 if you need to install the .NET Framework 1.0, and it will be v1.1.4322 if you need to install the .NET Framework 1.1.

If you end up seeing any error messages like this, you can re-install the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 in order to resolve the errors.  If you don't end up seeing any error messages like this, then you don't need to worry about re-installing the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1.

Hope this may helpful...

Comment: Here the above answers all are useful to everyone so +1.Hope my answer also will helpful to some one.