# .NET - what version of the framework am I currently running in (from C#)

Tags: c#, .net, version

Using C#, what is the best way to ask the .NET Runtime which version you are running under?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Environment.Version`.  This has the version number of the CLR currently running your code and is supported on all versions of the CLR.

Documentation

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx

Comment: This newer property is more accurate for after .NET Framework 4.5 System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription

Answer (score 6):

It is important to be careful about asking which version of the ***framework*** is running, and which version of the ***runtime*** is running, as they can be different. Your title and body ask subtly different questions.

@JaredPar is right on the money with the runtime version.

For framework versions, check out this closely-related post: [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: The latest installed version might not be the same as the current assembly is running under. Getting the current executing framework version should be easier than checking for installed versions. (but lack of answers in that regard points to that not being the case)

Answer (score 2):

- You can write a simple method for
  this purpose:

  ```
  public static void GetVersion() {   
   Environment.Version.ToString() }
  ```

The output is your .net version.

- You can also find the installed
  versions in the following location:

  ```
  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework
  ```
- If you are using Visual Studio, run
  Visual Studio commander from the
  start menu, and enter `clrver` , and it gives you the
  running version.
- And for sure, you can always check
  your registry for that:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ software \ Microsoft \ Net Framework \
  ```