# how to know the version of .NET? or convert a project from 4.0 to 4.5.1?

Tags: c#-4.0

I had a project which first target was .NET4.0 but now I change the project to 4.5.1, and I would like to know how to check the version of .NET, because I run the application in a fresh win7 and the application runs.

I try to use this code to check the version of .NET that is used:

```
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly
                     .GetExecutingAssembly()
                     .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                     .Where(x => x.Name == "System.Core").First().Version.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(version);
```

And the result is 4.0.0.0, so how I am thinking that the application is still 4.0. How can I change the target of the application?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - what version of the framework am I currently running in (from C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704449/net-what-version-of-the-framework-am-i-currently-running-in-from-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this if it helps. I have tested it in a web application. It's showing correct values.

```
var targetFrameWork =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute),false);
var frameWork = ((System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute)(targetFrameWork[0])).FrameworkName;
```

It returns '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'.

Note:

Environment.Version returns '4.0.30319.18444'.

```
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                             .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                             .Where(x => x.Name == "System.Core").First().Version.ToString();
```

It returns '4.0.0.0'.