# Is it possible to specify .NET service pack in "supportedRuntime" in app.config?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that runs fine on .Net 2.0 SP2, but fails to run properly on .NET 2.0 RTM. (FYI: It fails when calling a method a managed DLL that is a wrapper for a native DLL for USB programming).

I know you can give supported runtimes in the app.config of a C# .NET application

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.5727" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
```

However, is it also possible to specify a specific Service Pack version?

Thanks!

Edit: I did now find out which method fails between 2.0 and 2.0 SP2. It is WaitHandle.WaitOne(int) which was added in 2.0 SP1.

A tip for everyone else having the problem, the compiler doesn't say anything but if you  ngen the executable with the problematic runtime, it does give you the exact error.

E.g.:

```
Warning: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32)'. while resolving 0xa0000e1 - System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne.
11/11/2010 01:54:07 [3620]: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32)'. while compiling method XXX
```

Rogier

Comment: Check out...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great explanation can be found [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2009-02/msg00610.html) on why this is not possible. You can locate a SO response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed) to address your needs.

`<supportedRuntime>` doesn't actually work that way, because the 3.5 framework uses the 2.0 runtime. You can only specify *runtimes* that way, not *frameworks*, and the element only expresses preference, not demand.

Comment: OK, seems logical. I have taken care of all the details in my NSIS installer, but some users were copying the files to other PC's...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for .net 2.0 sp2):

```
<supportedRuntime version="2.0.50727.1433" />
```

[.NET Framework versions here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions)

Comment: Doesn't work.  Quoting: "The string value must match the directory name found under the .NET Framework installation root."

Comment: Well I did started the post with "Try". I will not delete it so that others can see that this is not a valid option.