# How do I detect what .NET version the application is running on?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried using `Environment.Version.ToString()` to determine what .NET framework on the target machine is in use, but it says I'm using .NET 2.0, when version 4.0 is installed.

How do I detect what version of the .NET Framework is running on the target machine?

Comment: Chicken and egg.  If your C# code runs then you already know you've got the .NET version that your code requires.

Comment: I know I has .NET framework installed on my computer, but I want to know the version on the target computer (Making a simple installer for checking)

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Environment.Version.ToString();` returns version of your application not system, you can read the version from registry or search in %windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework folders to find maximum number.

The registry key is `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\` see [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Answer (score 1):

To find out what versions of .NET are available on a machine, you need to look in the registry - see [Determine which versions and service pack levels of .NET Framework are installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/determine-dotnet-versions-service-pack-levels).
<sub>(Originally MSDN KB article 318785)</sub>