# Identify my dotnet version

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check from a c# application itself, what version of dotnet being used by application?

Comment: Did you mean the minimal version required by the application? (TargetFrameworkVersion attr in project file)

Comment: Actually I need path of current application framework. My application needs to execute some exe from current running version. i.e., if my application is using 2.0 it will pick exe from .net 2.0 folder and if using 4 it will pick exe from .net 4.0 folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) - it gives you the exact version of .NET running the application.

> Gets a Version object that describes the major, minor, build, and revision numbers of the common language runtime.

---

To find out what version of the framework is installed, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed) SO question and answers. In a nut shell, you will need to dig into the registry.

Comment: Can it distinguish between 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0? (the runtime is the same, 2.0.something)

Comment: @xanatos - No, it can't. It will return the runtime version. If you need to know what is installed, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed) SO question and answers.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the:

```
Environment.Version
```

to get the version number of the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Console app add this class and run it

```
 using Microsoft.Win32;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        public class GetDotNetVersion
        {
            public static void Get45PlusFromRegistry()
    {
        const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";
        using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
        {
            if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version: " +  CheckFor45PlusVersion((int)ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.");
            }
        }
    }

    // Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility.
    private static string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
    {
        if (releaseKey >= 394802)
            return "4.6.2 or later";
        if (releaseKey >= 394254)
        {
            return "4.6.1";
        }
        if (releaseKey >= 393295)
        {
            return "4.6";
        }
        if ((releaseKey >= 379893))
        {
            return "4.5.2";
        }
        if ((releaseKey >= 378675))
        {
            return "4.5.1";
        }
        if ((releaseKey >= 378389))
        {
            return "4.5";
        }
        // This code should never execute. 
        // that 4.5 or later is installed.
        return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
    }
 }
 // Calling the GetDotNetVersion.Get45PlusFromRegistry method produces 
 // output like the following:
 //       .NET Framework Version: 4.6.1
 }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual Studio, 
go to Tools->Nutget Package Management->Package Manager Console
Type in *dotnet --version*
And here you go!