# Detecting Internationalized .NET Versions

Tags: .net, frameworks, internationalization

I've found [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed) which addresses part of my problem.  Can I reliably use these registry keys to also detect (for internationalized installs) whether the culture-specific verison of the .NET framework is installed?  Or are there a completely different set of keys?  (I'm guessing there are, but have yet to find a complete listing for the 37 languages MS supports).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.  Every .NET install is the same throughout the world.  It gets localized by satellite assemblies.  There's no need to detect this, your user will figure out what language pack to download when the exception messages look funny.  I think it is automatic anyway.