# i want to know which .net CLR version my application is using

Tags: java, .net

i want to know which CLR version my application is using.

I "dont" want to use either **clrver.exe or GetCORVersion(),GetRequestedRuntimeInfo(),GetRequestedRuntimeversion()** as these ways are *Visual Studio* specific.
Is there any .net framework related exe/dll/api which will give me CLR versions
since i want to use the java language to know about it and need a way which also work when framework is present but not the VS. Registry key value will be a great option.
i want o/p like **clrver -all**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply: `Environment.Version`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment.getruntimedirectory.aspx)?

EDIT: If you only have access to the registry (if your program is not a .NET one), I suggest you use this SO answer: [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: i dont want to use any code from c# what i want is any exe or registry key value from where i could get the same.

Comment: @amod0017 - your question is not clear about that, as you said "dll/api". Please edit your question, the language your using, etc.

Comment: @simon i have seen the answer. what i require is clrver rather than the .net framework version.