# Product Code of .net Framework

Tags: .net, windows, registry

recently i was exploring the registry i found few special number in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\UNINSTALL\{...product code...}.` i found that these numbers are unique and are same on all the machines for a particular software. For example- microsoft .net framework 4.0 has `0A0CADCF-78DA-33C4-A350-CD51849B9702` product code. Can anyone list me the product code of all the .net framework (with service pack). i will suggest you all to have a look in registry path provided.
Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean version, or version number?

Comment: i google it these identification number are product code. have a look at the registry path i provided.(this will only work if u have externally installed the framework.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\UNINSTALL{...product code...}." this path stores the product code of the software and are unique on all the machine (depending on the OS (32bit or 64 bit))

i have collected few of the registry entries of .net framework they are as follows:-

1.1-     CB2F7EDD-9D1F-43C1-90FC-4F52EAE172A1

2.0 sp2- C09FB3CD-3DOC-3F2D-899A-61AD67F2073F

3.0 SP1- 2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783

3.0 SP2- A3051CD0-2F64-3813-A88D-B8DCCDE8F8C7

3.5 SP1- CE2CDD62-0124-36CA-84D3-9F4DCF5C5BD9

4.0-     0A0CADCF-78DA-33C4-A350-CD51849B9702

4.0 client profile- 3C3901C5-3455-3E0A-A214-0B093A5070A6

all are of 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)