# How to find out if .NET 4.02 is installed?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Microsoft has recently released some "update" for .NET Framework. 
Unfortunately, I don't know any way to find out which version is installed.
Framework-Version stays on 4.0.30319.239 (WTF - why use buildcounters?!)

Thanks for some enlightement ;-)

PS: Setting supportedRuntime in app.config to Version=4.0.2 makes the application tell me at startup that 4.0.2 is not installed (in no time - so there must be some place where the "real" version can be found)

Comment: Shouldn't this question be tagged `.net-4.0.2`? 4.0 answers might be different. :p

Comment: @harriyott sorry no, the registry keys don't tell anything about 4.0.2

Comment: You don't have it.  Revision 239 was a security patch pushed last month.  The 4.0.2 update has revision 245.  The 4.0.1 update was revision 233.  Use the FileVersionInfo class on mscorlib.dll

Comment: @Hans: I have this line in app.config `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.2,Profile=Client" />` and it runs fine (and just brings a messagebox on other system which don't have 4.0.2 installed) and `Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);` just returns 4.0.30319.239 there. According to the file list at this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544514/en-us) mscorlib.dll has not been touched; only some assemblies got this 245 revision.

Comment: @HansPassant and what is build .506?

Comment: This question does **NOT** cover exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic -- and there still is no answer.