# How can I find out if .NET 4.02 is installed?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I've asked [this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048107/how-to-find-out-if-net-4-02-is-installed) - it was closed as "exact duplicate" by some people who didn't take the time themselves to read questions / comments carefully!
So, another try - maybe it gets the time to receive some working answer before being closed for some pointless reason again.

Microsoft has recently released some "update" for .NET Framework. Unfortunately, I don't know any way to find out which version is installed. Framework-Version stays on `4.0.30319.239`.

Thanks for some enlightement ;-)

PS: Setting supportedRuntime in app.config to Version=4.0.2 makes the application tell me at startup that 4.0.2 is not installed (in no time - so there must be some place where the "real" version can be found).

Comment: What's the reason you want to detect it?

Comment: @HansPassant : Have you ever experienced that even when coding against 4.0.0.0.0 you get changes in behavior just because 4.0.2 EXISTS!? And why does it matter WHY he wants to know? I really want to know WHY the system knows that "4.0.2" is installed and whats the concept behind this shit by introducing dozens of 4.0 frameworks.

Comment: Why are people up voting this when you asked an identical question yesterday, and it was closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @slugster just look at the edit Oded has done.

Comment: @slugster: maybe they didn't get a proper answer yesterday because some especially smart people closed the question as duplicate without further investigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: @JohnSaunders possible offending comment

Comment: That's an automatic comment when a vote to close as duplicate occurs. How is it offending?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Are you kidding? Didn't you notice that the "possible duplicate" matters a totally different topic? Is everybody ignoring my comments to this and the already closed-as-duplicate-question? That's really a fine community of "experts" -- I'll call this the wikipedia admin-power syndrome.

Comment: I saw your claim and ignored it. Come up with some facts to show how this is any different from the question I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnSaunders facts are: 1. I answered the question by 2. not using anything mentioned in the "duplicate" question -- you **won't** find the word "sku" in your "duplicate" at all.

Comment: @springy76: how is this not the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed?

Comment: @JohnSaunders : **where** does your linked question differentiate between 4.0, 4.0.1 or 4.0.2? Try it -- the registry keys given by the answers **don't** contain any info about an existing 4.0.2 installation -- and most likely won't even show anything for the upcoming 4.5; which BTW currently (=CTP) is only based on 4.0.1

Comment: @springy76: you're right. I confused ".NETFramework" with "NET Framework Setup". I'll ask that my close vote be removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs
```

If you have installed 4.0.2 then there exist these additional nodes:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.1,Profile=Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.2
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.2,Profile=Client
```

Comment: What value / key should be in it when 4.0.2 is installed?

Comment: Okay, on my machine, it's only 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't make a difference. You don't target specific build numbers of the framework, you target the release number, which in this case is 4.0. What are you doing where you need to know the exact build number?

> WTF - why use buildcounters?!

Why wouldn't you? It details the **exact** version of the framework. Typically you don't release software with a round "this is version 1.0.0.0" because it can cause havoc with versioning for updates/hotfixes etc.

Simply targeting .NET 4.0 should be sufficient.

Comment: Did you spent any thought at any time that a developer might wish to know why his development machine acts different than any other machine in the company? And that this only happens because he has 4.0.2 installed which is visible nowhere but changes the behavior of programs which explicitely are targetting 4.0.0?

Comment: This question quacks like the classic XY question.  Question asks about vexing problem Y to actually attempt to solve X.  Which is easy to solve but nobody knows X.  The OP's dogged persistence only talking about Y doesn't help him get the answer he needs.  And insisting that answerers try to guess at X makes no sense.

Comment: @HansPassant it would be nice if you'd spend your efforts more in answering the question than writing useless comments with your personal opinion for which nobody has asked for.

Comment: Because 4.0.2 adds some features, particularly around SQL LocalDB.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give it a try:

If you know a special function/method inside a class that is only present in .NET 4.02 but not in .NET 4.0, I would use reflection to e.g. [get a list of all methods of a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx) or the signature of a specific method.

If there are only internal (methods/properties) changes, you could use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to search for such changes and then use again reflection to check for the changes.

On the other hand, I'm not sure whether some security constraints might hinder you from doing reflection.