# What is the connection string for localdb for version 11

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-2012, localdb

I'm trying to do the Code First Walkthrough of the entity framework ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx ).

I have the latest SQL Server Express and when I check my versions available via command line (*sqllocaldb info*): I see localdbApp1 and v11.0.  When I try to run the walkthrough with a few minor tweaks, I get a can't connect error.

My app.config looks like this:

```
<parameter value="Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I wrote a simple connection test like below and the code returns the same SQL Connection error ((provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)).

```
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True").Open();
```

I've tried replacing `"Data Source=..."` with `"Server=..."` but to no avail there.

Any ideas what the connection string should be?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the cause of the problem, because there may well be more, but backslashes are special in C# strings unless you precede them by `@`: `@"(LocalDB)\v11.0"`.

Comment: True I didn't add the @ symbol.  I did retry and returned the same result.

Comment: There is no database in your connection string.

Comment: This may b a silly question, but are you sure your application compiles for .NET 4.x? .NET 3.5 applications would give this error, since .NET 3.5 does not understand `(localdb)` server name.

Comment: Check my [answer][1] on a similar question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27459473/3506427

Comment: Also `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Answer (score 101):

1. Requires .NET framework 4 updated to at least 4.0.2. [If you have 4.0.2, then you should have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065002/how-can-i-find-out-if-net-4-02-is-installed)

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.2

If you have installed latest VS 2012 chances are that you already have 4.0.2. Just verify first.

2. Next you need to have an instance of `LocalDb`. By default you have an instance whose name is a single `v` character followed by the LocalDB release version number in the format xx.x. For example, `v11.0` represents SQL Server 2012. [Automatic instances are public by default. You can also have named instances which are private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). Named instances provide isolation from other instances and can improve performance by reducing resource contention with other database users. [You can check the status of instances using the `SqlLocalDb.exe` utility (run it from command line).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx)
3. Next your connection string should look like:

   "Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;"
   or

   "Data Source=(localdb)\test;Integrated Security=true;"

**from your code**. [They both are the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025055/server-vs-data-source-in-connection-string) Notice the two `\\` required because `\v` and `\t` means special characters. Also note that what appears after `(localdb)\\` is the name of your LocalDb instance. `v11.0` is the default public instance, `test` is something I have created manually which is private.

1. **If you have a database (.mdf file) already:**

   ```
    "Server=(localdb)\\Test;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName= myDbFile;"
   ```
2. **If you don't have a Sql Server database:**

   ```
    "Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;"
   ```

And you can create your own database programmatically:

a) **to save it in the default location with default setting:**

```
var query = "CREATE DATABASE myDbName;";
```

b) **To save it in a specific location with your own custom settings:**

```
// your db name
string dbName = "myDbName";

// path to your db files:
// ensure that the directory exists and you have read write permission.
string[] files = { Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, dbName + ".mdf"), 
                   Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, dbName + ".ldf") };

// db creation query:
// note that the data file and log file have different logical names
var query = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbName +
    " ON PRIMARY" +
    " (NAME = " + dbName + "_data," +
    " FILENAME = '" + files[0] + "'," +
    " SIZE = 3MB," +
    " MAXSIZE = 10MB," +
    " FILEGROWTH = 10%)" +

    " LOG ON" +
    " (NAME = " + dbName + "_log," +
    " FILENAME = '" + files[1] + "'," +
    " SIZE = 1MB," +
    " MAXSIZE = 5MB," +
    " FILEGROWTH = 10%)" +
    ";";
```

And execute!

A sample table can be loaded into the database with something like:

```
 @"CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
    (
        id int identity primary key, 
        type varchar(20), 
        details varchar(30)
    );
   INSERT INTO supportContacts
   (type, details)
   VALUES
   ('Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
   ('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');";
```

Note that `SqlLocalDb.exe` utility doesn't give you access to databases, you separately need [`sqlcmd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162773.aspx) utility which is sad..

Comment: Best answer i have ever seen! I just installed .Net 4.5.2 and everything is Done! With my Love! :))

Comment: it seems the connectionstring is case sensitive for me. I have to use "Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;" to get it to work.

Answer (score 20):

This is a fairly old thread, but since I was reinstalling my Visual Studio 2015 Community today, I thought I might add some info on what to use on VS2015, or what might work in general.

To see which instances were installed by default, type `sqllocaldb info` inside a command prompt. On my machine, I get two instances, the first one named **`MSSQLLocalDB`**.

```
C:\>sqllocaldb info
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV13
```

You can also create a new instance if you wish, using `sqllocaldb create "some_instance_name"`, but the default one will work just fine:

```
// if not using a verbatim string literal, don't forget to escape backslashes
@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;"
```

Comment: pasting this into a json file in VS automatically adds backslashes for me

Answer (score 19):

I installed the mentioned .Net 4.0.2 update but I got the same error message saying:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

I checked the SqlLocalDb via console as follows:

```sh
C:\>sqllocaldb create "Test"
LocalDB instance "Test" created with version 11.0.

C:\>sqllocaldb start "Test"
LocalDB instance "Test" started.

C:\>sqllocaldb info "Test"
Name:               Test
Version:            11.0.2100.60
Shared name:
Owner:              PC\TESTUSER
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    05.09.2012 21:14:14
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B8A5271F\tsql\query
```

This means that SqlLocalDb is installed and running correctly. So what was the reason that I could not connect to SqlLocalDB via .Net code with this connectionstring: **`Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;`**?

Then I realized that my application was compiled for DotNet framework 3.5 but SqlLocalDb only works for DotNet 4.0.

After correcting this, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem for a bit.
I noticed that I had:

```
Data Source= (localdb)\v11.0"
```

Simply by adding one back-slash it solved the problem for me:

```
Data Source= (localdb)\\v11.0"
```

Comment: yes - `"\v"` is a [vertical tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Escaping the `\` in some way is important.

Answer (score 3):

In Sql Server 2008 R2 database files you can connect with

```
Server=np:\\.\pipe\YourInstance\tsql\query;InitialCatalog=yourDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

only, but in sql Server 2012 you can use this:

> Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;Database=DB1;

and it depended on your `.mdf` `.ldf` version.

for finding programmicaly i use this Method that explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164208/sql-server-management-studio-local-database-connection-error-in-windows-7?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Dot Net 4.0.2 or above as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/27/net-framework-4-now-supports-localdb.aspx).
The 4.0 bits don't understand the syntax required by LocalDB

[See this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

You can dowload the update [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544514/en-us)

Comment: I've already downloaded the latest.  Here's what my Help->About ... shows:  Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Comment: I suppose you have the latest then. Just like mine. Checked on Presentation.Core.dll with version 4.0.30319.275 (vs 245 on microsoft update article)

Answer (score 1):

This is for others who would have struggled like me to get this working....I wasted more than half a day on a seemingly trivial thing...

If you want to use SQL Express 2012 LocalDB from VS2010 you must have this patch installed
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27756

Just like mentioned in the comments above I too had Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel and since its mentioned everywhere that you need "Framework 4.0.2 or Above" I thought I am good to go...

However, when I explicitly downloaded that 4.0.2 patch and installed it I got it working....

Answer (score 0):

I have connection string `Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;Database=DB1;`

and even a **.NET 3.5** program connects and execute SQL successfully.

But many people say .NET 4.0.2 or 4.5 is required.