# SQL Server Express Setup

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Just installed SQL Server Management Studio with Tools including LocalDB.  Went through entire setup without ever seeing an option to set the sa password nor setup any other users/logins with sysadmin rights.  So now I can't actually do anything in SSMS.  Permission is denied to create new database, change the sa password, etc.  Pretty useless until I can either log in as sa or setup my user with sysadmin rights.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you install an actual SQL Server engine, or did you perhaps choose only LocalDB? And are you trying to connect to the local Express instance, or to LocalDB?

Comment: I installed SQL Server 2012 Express Edition with Tools (x64).  During setup, there were two items checked to install.  I forget the first one but the second was LocalDB.  When I go into SSMS, I connect to .\SQLEXPRESS using windows authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During setup you should have seen a screen that offered you to choose mixed authentication for the database engine and also add Windows users to the sysadmin server role. Here's what it looked like:

[image]

Chances are you blew past it clicking Next > Next > Next. It's ok, we've all done that.

The easiest fix, I think, is to connect using SSMS via [PSExec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). This will allow you to connect as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, which has inherent sysadmin rights to SQL Server. You launch it with these options:

```
PsExec -s -i "C:\...path to ssms...\Ssms.exe"
```

This will run SSMS as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM using Windows Auth. You will be prompted to connect to a server, just enter `.\SQLEXPRESS` (make sure the service is running):

[image]

Then you can right-click your instance and change the authentication mode to mixed (Properties > Security), reset the sa password under Security > Logins, and add your Windows login as a sysadmin.

You can also see this answer if that doesn't get you everything:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12164306/61305

Comment: Thanks.  I must not be installing the correct thing then because I definitely never saw that window.  I specifically combed through all windows during installation as this is my 2nd time installing and I figured I must've missed something the first time around. I installed SQL Server 2012 Express Edition with Tools (x64) from TechNet.

Comment: And you're sure you selected Database Engine on the Feature Selection screen? It's not checked by default.

Comment: Yes.  Database Engine, Server = .\SQLEXPRESS.  But the user name is grayed out and it is currently my username and not NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.  I have confirmed in SQL Server Configuration Manager that SQLSERVER(SQLEXPRESS) is running and set to logon as NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE.  But it still tries to connect as me.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question I think.  The only two options I had during feature selection were Management Tools Basic and LocalDB. Both of which I checked.

Comment: You need to download PsExec in order to connect to the engine as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. I provided a link in my answer.

Comment: And if you didn't see [these options](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ANd.png) during setup, you're either using the wrong executable, or you chose the wrong option in the installation center.