# Unable to publish ASP.NET database to external server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC application to my server running Windows Server 2008.

I have installed IIS 
I have created a database in on the (LocalDb)\v11.0 server on the destination server (The DB is named TestPublishWebApp).

[image]

I've clicked publish and have set the connection (and validated the connection):
[image: connection]
And I have set the settings as well:
[image]

However whenever I publish the application I and go to the URL I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

This is the very first time I'm trying to publish an application to an external server. What could I be doing wrong?

And yes, I have verified that the SQL server is running.

Comment: why dont you try creating database on an actual sql server instance rather than localdb. i guess it cant find localdb

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno)