# Error when connecting to local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, local

I have a C# web application which works fine when I use it in debug mode or run it inside of Visual Studio. If I map a domain to it via IIS I get the following error (translated from German):

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Error in the local database Runtime. It's not possible to automatically create an instance.

I already gave my AppPool permission do access the `App_Data` folder (and Root).

Comment: Maybe have a look at this previous post and answer, it suggest changing the connection string because of changes in LocalDB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno

Comment: but he has the problem while debugging. Which works fine for me. In fact the Programm runs perfectly till I add a Domain.