# SQL Server error: 50 when trying to add .mdf file to App_Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, error-handling

I was creating a web site project in Visual Studio 2015, created an `App_Data` folder and tried to add a SQL Server database file.

This error occurred:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (v12.0). I checked the connection in SQL Server Configuration Manager, the server connection is enabled, my TCP/IP port is set to 1443, my Firewall is set for the connection as well.

I am able to connect to my server from Visual Studio Tools/Connect to Database Option, it's able to connect either to my server or to a local database. When I test my connection from there, it works.

I also see the connection is enabled and running from server explorer, and when I drag and drop an SQL DataSource Wizard from my ToolBox to an aspx page, the wizard sees the database and is ready to import it as well.

I also have tried double checking the connection under services.msc from cmd and it's all up and running.

Yet, when I want to right click and add a SQL Server database file to my `App_Data` folder, this error comes up.

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: What is the server name you are providing when you trying to connect?

Comment: To be able to use these "free-floating" `.mdf` database file, you **must have** SQL Server **Express** (or LocalDB = Express for devs) installed. Any other edition *will NOT work*. Do you have Express or LocalDB installed and ready to use?

Comment: Yes, I do have SQLEXPRESS and have my LocalDB configured.

Comment: krish, the server I'm trying to use is my LocalDB, I have Connected Visual Studio with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (localdb)\mssqllocaldb as server name to connect to the LocalDB automatic instance. for more information read this article: http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2014_0010.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation (and SQL Express users having the same problems)

### **1. Check that SQL Express (master-) database exists and is reachable**

In Server Explorer => Data Connections => Add Connection

- (LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb
- (LocalDb)\v12.0
- (LocalDb)\v11.0

For further SQL Express problems see: 
[SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno)

### **2. Configure Default Connection in Visual Studio**

If you upgraded SQL Express the wrong connection string still resides in the VS configuration

Tools => Options => Databas Tools => Data Connections -> "(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb"