# Local Database Runtime error occurred

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project (download from [here](https://fil.email/2DmSPC)). I can run this without any error from Visual Studio. But if I hosted the project into IIS using a tool (code from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/06/08/iis7-sample-code-for-addingdeleting-a-website-programmatically-c-example/)). If I launch the page from web browser, it shows error as "Local Database Runtime error occurred" like below screenshot.

[image: Local Database Runtime error]

Comment: Please make sure that Service for SQL server is running..

Comment: In your dev environment you are pointing to a local instance of Sql Server, right?....now, when you deploy your site to IIS is in another server, am I correct?

Comment: @user55 How can I check it?

Comment: @Hackerman What to do to resolve this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis/) can be helpful for you..

Comment: [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis/) helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the applicationHost.config file by adding the below child element into the appPool fixed the issue for me.

```
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
```

*File location: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config*

Example:

```
<add name="SampleAppPool">
     <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

Comment: Note that if you want to edit this file make sure you use a 64 bit text editor like notepad. If you use a 32 bit one like Notepad++ it will automatically edit a different copy of the file in SysWOW64 instead.