# Visual Studio-Asp.net Login Database not working after publishing a website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, authentication, webforms

I am using VS 2013 - Webforms to create a simple website. I am using inbuilt login mechanism of asp.net webforms. When i run it on the my machine all is working fine. But when i publish a website it says database cannot be found.
My Connection string is

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mywebsite-98edcb77-c971-4183-8070-4a6632b18ace;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mywebsite-98edcb77-c971-4183-8070-4a6632b18ace.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local
>   Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance.
>   See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +6568734    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6595176
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +219
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597526
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6598067
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +6601321
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +103
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +1079
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   +6605815    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +233
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +278    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +263
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +325
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +575
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +372
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +118
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +459
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +48
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting
>   provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity
>   Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +238
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +83
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +223
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +118
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +94
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +248
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +618    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +26
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +21    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +68    System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +85
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +696
>
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +214
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +144
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +84    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +49    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +755    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +144
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +84    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__4.MoveNext()
>   +447    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +144
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +84    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +49    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +752    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +144
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +84    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
>   +859    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +144
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +84    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +49    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +239    Account_Register.CreateUser_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +134
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +155    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3804

Comment: what changes ??

Comment: First: *not working after publishing a website* Where you have published?

Comment: Internet Information Services

Comment: Are you sure you getting an error of *database cannot be found*? can you add full error in your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno

Comment: @Div what changes in connection string are required

Comment: Did you go through upper link?

Comment: Have you tried to change `(LocalDb)\v11.0` to `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: tried ... not working

Answer (score 0):

may not work in IIS publish because LocalDb is not intended for product purposes.

For that reason ,Microsoft recommends to use SQLServerExpress for product purpose.

I have also have same ISSUE for SQL Server Compact .Migrating to Sql Server Express does resolve the issues .

you can see the  [limitation](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/38660-Using-SQL-CE-vs-SQL-Express-in-Production)

Comment: but how can use in-built login database then?

Comment: Use Sql Express Edition for login and other stuff in production environment...For unknown reason i also faced same and found the thing i explain before you

Comment: how to migrate my current localDB to Sql Express, and what changes will be required in connection string

Comment: Please  check  this link http://akash365.com/2016/10/25/publish-asp-net-login-to-production-with-schema/

Answer (score 0):

For your continence

1.Views ->Sql Server Object Explorer

2.Login to Your Data base by Windows Authentication

3.Right click +Extra data tier Application

4.Choose Schema or Data with database with yourName

5.Then Publish Data tier with select yourName file (it works as Backup file) and Target database will be your production.

Then check it works…