# Can not add a localDB in my website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I installed visual studio2015 then when
I tried to add a database file to my project but every time i tried to do it this message show up

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 –
Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
) (Microsoft SQL Server 2012)

Comment: error message tells you everything you need to know there. Sounds like your connection string is wrong. Update your question with that string

Comment: Did you install sql server to your local machine? If you didnt you can install developer edition here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: I have sql server 2012 and it's working great but when I'm trying to add a new mdf file from visual studio 2015 this message show up

Comment: possible sql server services stop check it

Comment: Sql services working

Comment: Again, provide the connection string you are using.... Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno

Comment: Does the `new mdf file` exist on your local server?