# MVC Web Deploy with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to deploy my application that uses Entity Framework. When publishing, I use Publish Method set to `Web Deploy` to localhost (since I deploy it from the server). Then my Visual Studio asks me about Databases, so I point out the databases that the project uses (it is MSSQL Local DB and the other one is SQL Server DB). Whole publish works and and the connections are fine (as Visual Studio validates it). However, after publishing, the web application says:

> Error.
>   An error occured while processing your request.

The application is already on server, seems fine, but whenever I try to access the database, this error shows up. What should I change?

Comment: First off, you need to get the full exception..

Comment: @stuartd How do I get a full exception since I cannot debug it?

Comment: Set [customErrors to OFF in the config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) and you'll see the full error on the page.

Comment: @stuartd this didn't help at all. The error is still not visible

Comment: Okay so I managed it and the error says `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)` @stuartd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno