# Error when trying to create DB: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to write application in ASP.NET, already created Models, Context and want to create DB with EF Code-First approach, but it does not work.

Additionally, folder `App_Data` is empty. I have installed SQL Server 2017 Express.

I tried every possible solution I could find, still, nothing worked.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-BM-20171207072135.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BM-20171207072135;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

However, I get this error:

```
PM> update-database 

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
> statements being applied to the target database
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.
>
> Errors:
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>       ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

>

> Error Number:-1983577846,State:0,Class:20
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start)

Comment: While running that `update-database` in console, ensure that you're targeting the right `project`. You can also check in VS if you can connect to your `LocalDB` instance (that's what your connection string is using).

Comment: Yea, working on right project (always checking "Default project" above console). How can I check this connection? Can't find any servers in VIEW->SERVER EXPLORER except "DESKTOP-KV92T89", but it doesn't have any databases

Comment: This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno) goes through quite a bit trying to figure out `localdb` - version, installed, etc. (your conn string _looks_ ok though). In any case, since you can connect to that instance of SQL, why not use it for now. You can create a database and point to it. Comment out your conn string above, copy it and change accordingly (pointing to what looks like SQL Express). Make sure you retain the name `DefaultConnection` as thats configured in EF at the moment.

Comment: Have you even **installed** SQL Server LocalDB ?? When you open a Windows command prompt - can you run `sqllocaldb versions` - and if so, what's your output?`

Comment: It throws out
`Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0.`
Thought, that localdb will install itself automatically with sql express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your sql server is up and running. Look from windows services (services.msc). Or to make sure, try to connect first manually using VS DB connection or SSMS.

Try to check this this (below) from your sql service properties too.
[image]

Comment: That propably worked, mdf file appeared in App_Data folder and I got no errors when trying to update-database in PM console. Thank You very much!

Additionally, I put in CMD:
`sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`
and then 
`sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`

Everything works like a charm.