# Stumped trying to connect IIS 7 to my localdb running inside of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-7, localdb

For the life of me I am unable to connect to my localdb hosted database created in Visual Studio 2015 to my local IIS 7 instance running on the same machine.  IIS Express works fine but when I wanted to test things as a user outside of my network I dabbled with a Local copy of IIS.

I have tried everything from ensuring the app pools have the right privileges, that my connection strings are accurate and just about every thing else I have found on the web but I cannot for the life of me get this working.

The error I am getting is the following: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.
 )

Connection String in VS2015:

Any other details needed to help troubleshoot ask and I will provide.

Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: Use SQL Server Express instead!

Comment: is that a feature of VS2015 or a separate install altogether?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno