# .NET Core API cannot connect to MS LocalDB

Tags: .net-core, localdb

I am writing a .NET Core 2.1 web API using MS LocalDB. I can connect to my DB fine using SSMS and the server name `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` with Windows Authentication.

The API fails to connect with the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

My connection string is:

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Foo;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

As a side note, I tried to check my LocalDB version with `sqllocaldb v` but got the following error:

`Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0.`

Is my LocalDB installation completely borked?

Comment: You might have to change the instance name. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno

Comment: I can't find anything about renaming an instance there. However, I have tried creating a brand new instance and now get a different exception:

provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I've had to give up for now and switch to a remote SQL box.

Answer (score 1):

its kinda late but i am trying this for 2 days and finally found the answer.

1. When app is running on IIS
   --> go to advance setting in the application pool, then on change "Process Model->Load Profile" to TRUE;
2. when app is running on Kestrel,
   a. connection string "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb"... etc

hope this help the others.