# Cannot Connect to Server - (with adding a new class and connecting to DB)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

So I can actually connect to the server as it is localhosted.  But when I created a class called Merchant and add the /Merchants to my local host address I get the above error, even though the server does just fine with all the other pages from the web site.

This is my first time messing with C# and Visual Studios, and I am following a tutorial but I got stuck here.

Using MS Visuals 2013, MCV 5.

Here is the Merchants function:

```
    // GET: Merchants
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Merchants.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=         (LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150610102919.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20150610102919;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is the full error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a
>   Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
>   properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
>   enabled.)

Comment: Is the database service running and are you able to connect via the sql management studio?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540438/what-is-the-connection-string-for-localdb-for-version-11

Comment: It appears I many not even have SQL on my laptop, strange.  Gonna try to get it on there first then get back to this.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2012 (11.0) or later installed, so you already have SQL Server localdb. Inside VS, go to VIEW->SQL Server Object Explorer and you will be able to check which SQL Local DB versions you have installed in your environment.

Comment: Once I get to the Server Object Explorer I can't find out where to find the version I am using.