# How can the very same assembly behave differently when used by an 4.5 or 4.6 app?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, .net-4.6

A quote out of [What's New in 4.6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6 RC, `Task` and `Task<TResult>`
>   objects inherit the culture and UI culture of the calling thread. The
>   behavior of apps that target previous versions of the .NET Framework,
>   or that do not target a specific version of the .NET Framework, is
>   unaffected.

I always thought that there only exists v4.0.30319 at the assembly level for 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6 -- and that 4.6 is only an inplace update for 4.0-4.5.2?

To my [current knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066145/442376) the specified version in the app.config file only triggers a message box if the SKU is not installed at all -- how can this affect how assemblies behave?

Comment: Too early for me to try, but the simple explanation is that it pays attention to the [TargetFrameworkAttribute](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/versioning/targetframeworkattribute.cs,6a3c751444d92d65,references).  As you can tell from the references, it is already used to turn features on.

Comment: @HansPassant this would mean the framework is full of runtime version checks (maybe using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName`?) simulating older versions? I yet did not spot how `System.Uri` decides to behave differently if the app targets 4.5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

This page says it all,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Culture and task-based asynchronous operations**
>
> The task-based asynchronous programming pattern uses Task and
>   Task objects to asynchronously execute delegates on thread
>   pool threads. The specific thread on which a particular task runs is
>   not known in advance, but is determined only at runtime.
>
> For apps the target the .NET Framework 4.6 RC or later versions,
>   culture is part of an asynchronous operation's context. In other
>   words, starting with apps the target the .NET Framework 4.6 RC,
>   asynchronous operations by default inherit the values of the
>   CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of the thread from
>   which they are launched. If the current culture or current UI culture
>   differs from the system culture, the current culture crosses thread
>   boundaries and becomes the current culture of the thread pool thread
>   that is executing an asynchronous operation.
>
> The following example provides a simple illustration. **It uses the
>   TargetFrameworkAttribute attribute to target the .NET Framework 4.6
>   RC.** The example defines a Func delegate, formatDelegate,
>   that returns some numbers formatted as currency values. The example
>   changes the current system culture to either French (France) or, if
>   French (France) is already the current culture, English (United
>   States). It then:
>
> - Invokes the delegate directly so that it runs synchronously on the    main app thread.
> - Creates a task that executes the delegate    asynchronously on a thread pool thread.
> - Creates a task that executes    the delegate synchronously on the main app thread by calling the    Task.RunSynchronously method.

You can see from the code sample to see how to explicitly mark your program as .NET 4.6 targeted. Then CLR uses the new behavior. For all assemblies without such an attribute, or the value is not 4.6, the old behavior is kept.

Comment: and how does the assembly referenced by the program behave differently now? For example System.Uri (in System.dll) starts to preserve path segments that have more than two consecutive dots (such as http://localhost/dir1/.../dir2) starting with 4.5 -- LinqPad (which targets 4.0) doesn't preserve them, but is using the very same System.dll which is at version 4.5.2 here. (I can't spot any framework detecting code in System.Uri using ILSpy)

Comment: There can be many breaking changes and each has its own remediation tips. I am not able to give you a universal solution, neither Microsoft.

Comment: You still have not answered my question by any means. When I have installed 4.6 then on my system there is no 4.0 or 4.5 anymore. How is it done? What does the TargetFrameworkAttribute change?

Comment: @spring76, the .NET 4.0/4.5 behavior remains in .NET 4.6, while it is possible to enable new behavior by changing the TargetFrameworkAttribute in an assembly. What runtime you specify in app.config won't affect that at all.