# Accessing localdb on Windows7

Tags: c#, localdb

I developed an application in c# using VS 2013. EntityFramework 6.0, runtime version v4.0.30319, on my Windows 7 desktop

I can connect to the the localdb using SSMS.
I see this when I type sqllocaldb.exe info v11.0

```
Name: v11.0
Version: 11.0.3000.0
State: Running
```

Code:

```
using (var test = new myDataContextEntities())
{

 var yy = from x in test.names select x;
 Console.WriteLine(yy.ToList().Count);
}
```

In app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDataContextEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AnalysisModel.csdl|res://*/AnalysisModel.ssdl|res://*/AnalysisModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;initial catalog=Analysis;integrated security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Problem: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString

I checked that 4.02 is installed as suggested. [How can I find out if .NET 4.02 is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065002/how-can-i-find-out-if-net-4-02-is-installed)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an invalid character after "provider connection string="