# What error should I get if the program must use .Net framework and user have not installed one?

Tags: .net

This is kind of a silly question because most people ask the opposite such as: Why am I getting this and this error. LOL

But my question is what error will I get when I am trying to run .Net framework program while not having it installed?

I don't have a PC with out .Net framework so I cannot check in short notice.

Please point out the error.

I need this because I am creating a FAQ in help section of my program and I am trying to be specific.

Comment: Your application installer should check the availability of the particular .NET framework your app requires. In case it's not present you have to ask your user to download it or offer that possibility in your installer

Comment: If you're using one of the built in VS setup projects, it will automatically check for the correct version and have the user download it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application installer should check the availability of the particular .NET framework your app requires. In case it's not present you have to ask your user to download it or offer that possibility in your installer. There is a similar question thar responds to this: [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: Can you please point me where I could read about how to do this?

Comment: @HelpNeeder there is a similar question on stack overflow. See link

Comment: I would like to refer to this link. But I have no idea how to work on registry ect. To make question easier, I know there must be an error while starting up a program with out having .Net installed. I just can't remember what. I guess I wont worry about version checking because it's beyond my skills that I have at this moment. Googling didn't help me much since I don't know what the error might say.

Comment: Your code won't execute, there isn't much thing you can do besides checking for .NET availability. This assumes of course that installer is basically a native app that can run without .NET dependencies and make that check for you before installing your .NET app. Take a look at wix: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ok, I will take some time and try to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From a code aspect you will get no error.  Your code will never execute so you won't get an error.  If you ngended your code I'm not really sure what would happen, but I would assume the exe wouldn't load because of a missing dependency.