# Does Fluent Migrator support .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.5, fluent-migrator

Recently I'm heard about FluentMigrator and its features and really amazed about it and I want to use this in my new project in .NET Framework 4.5 and when I checked in github I saw that the newest release supports 3.5 and 4.0 and they didnt mention about 4.5 and I googled for any news about 4.5 with fluent migrator and I didnt get any satisfying result so I want to know is it possible to use Fluent Migrator with .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, .NET 4.0 assemblies will work in a .NET 4.5 project. The 4.5 CLR is a new version of the CLR but is backwards compatible with 4.0. See this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810391/will-net-4-5-introduce-a-new-version-of-the-clr) and this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) from Scott Hanselman.

So if you have a class project which is set to target .NET 4.5 and add the .NET 4.0 version of FluentMigrator as a reference (or install the Nuget package) then it will just work.

For FluentMigrator there is no major benefit of having a .NET 4.5 package, due to having to support .NET 3.5, none of the new .NET 4.5 features can be used yet.