# Check .net framework 3.5 installed on local machine with win a application which is built in same environment

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I need to check current .NET version installed on local machine, but my main task is to check is there a .net 3.5 version installed. My app is built in same .NET environment, 3.5. Is there any solution?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed

Comment: If the required framework version is not installed, your app will give you an error message when you try to start it.

Comment: Do you mean during installation? Because your application won't run if .NET 3.5 is not installed.

Comment: Yes during installation. I know that it won't work, but I wanna make a prerequisites list and I have not found yet a algorithm which can check .NET 3.5 with application which is also made in same environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing some sort of installer, look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)...