# xbap not detecting .NET runtime properly

Tags: .net, clickonce, xbap

In  my company we have built a full trust xbap app that will be downloaded over the public internet to customers. It requires .NET 4.0. If I run it on  machine without .NET 40 at all, it detects that, and installs the 4.0 files and then runs correctly. If only the 4.0 client profile is on and NOT Framework 4.0 Extended, the detection fails and the application does not load. Apparently some customers have this configuration.

Is this a known problem? Are there any work arounds?

Thanks
Harold

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing your xbap with ClickOnce? Can you check the prerequisites you have selected and make sure it's .NET 4 and not .NET 4 CF?

Comment: The server is setup now to execute the xbap directly after signing into the site... will executing the .deploy files behave differently?

Comment: No. If you go into the properties of your project, what version of .NET are you targeting? Is it .NET 4 or .NET 4 CF? If it's .NET 4 Extended, does it need to target that, or can it work against the CF?