# What versions of .net are divided into client and full versions?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to implement:

```
bool IsFullDotNetVersion()
{

}
```

(I need to know if System.Web is present in runtime in a Excel plugin I'm writing.)

I've been directed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed/199783#199783) but it's answer doesn't clearly describe if it's enough to check if the registry key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Install" is present.

Is it?

Aren't other versions of .Net divided into client or full versions?

What are the steps (registry keys?) I need to take to determined in any environment if the full version of .Net is installed?

Comment: Based on msdn only .Net 4 has a [client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.100).aspx). The definitive KB article on [.Net detection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785/en-us)

Comment: Writing .NET code to check if .NET installed is not very productive.  The simple approach is to just provide an installer that gets your Excel addin deployed and also installs the full version.  If it is already there then the bootstrapper quickly quits.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't check if the full profile is installed, but if the classes/assemlies you're interested in are present. i.e. use feature detection instead of version detection.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: what's the best way to do feature detection?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. Essentially you do what you want to do, and add error handling for the case that the assembly doesn't load, or the type you need isn't present. In your case the simples approach is probably using `Assembly.Load` on `System.Web.dll` and checking if that failed.