# Install correct .net version with application (not using Clickonce)

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, publish, iexpress

When publishing a .net application (it's in C#) not using Clickonce, how can I ensure that the correct version of the framework (e.g. 4.0), will be installed along with the application if not already installed?

<sup>When publishing using Clickonce, Clickonce can automatically detect whether the targeted version of .net is installed on the target computer, and if it isn't - download and install it automatically. What if I don't use Clickonce, but rather iexpress or any other packaging system?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be somewhat related to the question [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed), so I'm linking to it here for reference.

Essentially, there's no built-in support in [iexpress](/questions/tagged/iexpress) to detect the .NET framework and install it; you have to do this yourself. Theoretically you could write something in batch for this; a simple example could look like:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Check if .NET 4.0 is installed; if not, try to install it
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Install
if not errorlevel 0 dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q /norestart

rem Check if the install was successful; if it was, install app
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Install
if not errorlevel 0 exit /b 1

::[...install app, etc...]
```

Bundle a copy of .NET 4.0 (`dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe`) in the IExpress archive, set that batch file as your *install command* (eg `cmd /c install.bat`), and set *Long File Name support*.