# How to check if .NET Framework 4.0.2 is already installed - clickOnce

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, clickonce, bootstrapper

I am using localDb in my c# application and I read on msdn that the minimal version of the .net framework to run it is V4.0 with the 4.0.2 update. So, now I want to create a clickOnce that will check if the 4.0.2 update is already install and if not, install it. The problem is that I don't know how to check if this update is already installed or not.

To create my package, I'm using Bootstrapper manifest generator. I guess I just have to look in registry to see if the current version of the framework is equal or greater than 4.0.2, but the version don't change with the update. The only thing I found is looging at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.2
```

but there is no key, except (default), but that key contains no data. And I don't know to what file to look to see the version. So, I was wondering, how I'm suppose to do to see if that update is install ?

I hope I make myself clear and a great thank you in advance,

David

Answer (score 0):

You can try with using:-

```
AboutTools.FrameworkVersions().ToConsole();
```

Check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)