# How can I check if .NET is installed using Perl?

Tags: .net, perl

I would like to write a Perl script that checks if .NET 3.5 is installed. I want to check it because it calls some .NET stuff which does not work if it is missing.

Is there an easy way to determine if .NET is installed?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/199783/116923) answers tells you to use the registry to check for .Net versions. I suspect your next question will be how to query the registry using perl :)

Comment: And the answer to that would be [Win32::TieRegistry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::TieRegistry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trust the Registry, you can use the [Win32::TieRegistry](http://www.metacpan.org/modules/Win32::TieRegistry) module from CPAN and look for the right key based on the Microsoft documentation for [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx). It's a bit tricky if you need .NET 3.5 and above because you have to check for different keys for versions below or above 4.