# Is it possible that .Net is installed but not enabled?

Tags: .net, windows

In windows, is it possible that .Net is installed on a system but is not enabled ?

If so how can it be enabled via a c++ program ?

Comment: What do you mean by enabled? .NET is either installed or not :)

Comment: Why do you think its present but not enabled?

Comment: ASP.NET can be enabled or disabled in IIS - is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Just curious... Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Panayotis : typically, during installation (or running) of an app that will need .Net down the road (an installer for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net is either installed, or it is not. It cannot be installed but not "enabled", whatever that means.

The installation can be corrupted, which means some parts of .Net would work, and others would not. You most often find this problem on old XP computers, and on machines which have been attacked by virus.

You can detect whether .Net is installed through the registry : [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

## Update - IIS

A comment on the OP made a good point: you can indeed have .Net installed, but not activated (or rather, not correctly configured) **on IIS**.

To make sure .Net is enabled on IIS, run:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Then you will have to configure the IIS application pools to use the correct version of the .Net framework for what you want; currently it's either .Net 2, which includes 3.0 and 3.5, or .Net 4, which includes 4.5.

[More information here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1172907.aspx?Enabling%20ASP%20NET%204%200%20in%20IIS%207%205) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx).