# How do you find out what version of .Net framework is installed in your system

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

How do you find out what version of .Net framework is installed in your system?

Comment: You can have multiple versions of the .NET Framework installed, side-by-side. Are you asking from a user's perspective or from code? If it's from code, do you mean listing the currently installed versions or the version executing the current program?

Comment: Say I'm a user and I do not know anything about .net. Then when someone asks me what version of .net I have them how would I know about it?

Comment: goto control panel --> user program and features --> list of installed programs.. Here u will get all the version of .NET frameworks installed on your system

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but a "user" wouldn't go on stackoverflow and ask that, they'd just google it. This doesn't appear to be a code / programming related question.


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using windows explorer, go to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework ( or Framework64).  There will be a folder for each version of .NET installed.

Answer (score 0):

Build a tiny application with that code and provide it to your user:

```
    If Environment.Version.ToString <> "" Then
        NetFramework = ".NET Framework " & Environment.Version.ToString
    ElseIf Not  IsNothing(Type.GetType("System.Runtime.GcLargeObjectHeapCompationMode", False)) Then
        NetFramework = ".NET Framework 4.5.1"

    ElseIf Not IsNothing(Type.GetType("System.Runtime.GcLargeObjectHeapCompationMode", False)) Then
        NetFramework = ".NET Framework 4.5"
    Else

        Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim appVersion As String = ass.GetReferencedAssemblies.Where(Function(x) x.Name = "System.Core").First().Version.ToString

        NetFramework = ".NET Framework " & appVersion

    End If

    msgbox(NetFramework)
    end
```