# Umbraco 7.3 / .NET 4.5 installation via Visual Studio NuGet

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to install Umbraco 7.3 into an empty project using Visual Studio Professional 2013, and that Umbraco version is dependent upon .NET 4.5, which I should have according to `Help > About` under Visual Studio, as the listed version is 4.5.50938. However, the package errored when I tried to install it with NuGet Package Manager, saying I didn't have the required version.

In trying to ascertain installed versions and checking my registry (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/199783/1140630), all the listed versions are v4 and below consistent with the error.

Any idea what I'm missing and why the mismatch? And why Umbraco shouldn't install: is it something to do with the Visual Studio .NET version not being in my registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I created a Visual Studio Solution, then I add a empty MVC Project.

You need to make sure that the Framework in the properties for the project is set to .Net 4.5 for definite - before trying to add the Umbraco package via Nuget Package Manager.

Then you should be good to run it locally via your VS instance... and then publish it to a IIS application.

Comment: This turned out to be right, I'd been creating projects as 4.0 (the default) because of VS's less-than-perfect UI, preventing Umbraco installing in. Still curious as to where in the registry 4.5 is but that's irrelevant now at least. Thanks!