# I need a code which checks if "Microsoft .Net Framework 4" is installed or not?

Tags: vb.net

Following code checks if Microsoft Excel is installed into your computer.

```
    Dim officeType1 As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application")
    If officeType1 Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Microsoft Excel is not installed!")
    End If
```

Question: I need a code which checks if "Microsoft .Net Framework 4" is installed or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/199080/62576 is one of the many already existing posts about detecting the presence of a .NET version. Did you spend any time researching this topic before posting your question?

Comment: @Thanks Ken White, but that source very complicated for me...

Comment: There are other posts that have other source. My point is that you apparently did zero research before posting here, including failing to do a basic search (or even look at the suggested list of duplicates that were shown as you typed your question, and that are now in the list of related questions to the right of your post below the job ads). We expect you to make at least a minimal effort to find a solution yourself before posting here.

Comment: VB.Net runs inside the .Net framework. If your check code is executing, it's installed.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, there are plenty of other references. A quick search would yield many different ways to check for a .NET version.

You could check for a registry key, but A very simple way could just be looking for a directory such as:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

So you'd be looking at something like this

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319") Then
  'do something
End If
```

Comment: @ beatles1235, Thanks for answer. But are you sure existing of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 file means it is installed? Because I have C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 file but it isnt installed!