# Is there a way to see what .Net versions have been installed on a server

Tags: .net

Is there a log file or registry path  or script that will tell me any / all .Net versions installed on a server (2012 R2)? I have a need to see if .Net 4.6 was ever installed but when I run the following it jumps versions and I can't tell if 4.6 was installed:

ls -r 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v*' | foreach { $_.getValue('Version') } | sort -unique
2.0.50727.4927
3.0.30729.4926
3.0.4506.4926
3.0.6920.4902
3.5.30729.4926
4.0.0.0
4.7.02558

Thoughts please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-do-i-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: What you asked is not different from the existing thread. Since 4.x are in-place upgrade of each other, the detected .NET Framework 4.7 on the machine you tested tells a lot itself already.