# How do I detect .Net Framework 4.7.2 using wix 3.11 burn

Tags: wix

I have been trying out to have .net Framework 4.7.2 as a prerequisite for my installer.
I have done below in the bundle file

= $(var.NetFx46MinRelease)]]>

But with these changes I am unable to detect the Framework.
The installer proceeds for installation even it does not have 4.7.2 or higher.
I want the bootstrapper to detect and not the Msi.

Did anyone face the same issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below links

https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5575

[Install .NET Framework 4.7.2 (if needed) with WIX installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640255/install-net-framework-4-7-2-if-needed-with-wix-installer/53669005?noredirect=1#comment94259347_53669005)